# Moment.js - Creating "time" only variable from input form

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, angular-reactive-forms

you'd think this would be straightforward, but I have an `<input type="time">` where the user puts a time in. That field gives me the following output: `16:30`. So, basically it changes the way it appears in the input, which is `--:-- --` for `04:30 PM`.

(btw, this is an Angular reactive form using Material)

So, from the form, the string I have to work with is: `16:30`

I can kind of turn it into a moment object like this:

```
let timeTwelve = moment(this.webcastForms.value[0].time, 'HH:MM');
```

Which is I console.log gives me some kind of big object. I was hoping the time would then be in moment so I could format it how I need to. So, I tried with:

```
let timeTwelve = moment(this.webcastForms.value[0].time, 'HH:MM').format('hh:mm A');
```

which outputs: `invalid date`.

No clue why it's doing this. Any ideas?

(Bonus, I have a date too, and I'd like to create a third variable that's both combined in the format of `MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a (08/26/2016 09:00 AM)`. How can I add my time to a date, or maybe make a new moment object, and pass in the date and also time?)

Thanks for any help!

**(for reference, my date is a moment already)**

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: {…}, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: 
    Locale, …}
    _d: Mon Sep 24 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
    _i: {year: 2018, month: 8, date: 24}
    _isAMomentObject: true
    _isUTC: false
    _isValid: true
    _locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: 
    "Invalid date", ordinal: ƒ, _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, …}
    _pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
    __proto__: Object
```

Comment: How does the console.log object look like (where you mentioned it in the question)? And what exactly is the value of `this.webcastForms.value[0].time` ? Did you miss the 'am/pm' format? Also, what version of momentjs are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment is giving invalid date since it expects time to be associated with some date.

If your date and time both are string why don't you try something like

```
moment(`${dateStr}T${timeStr}`).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a")
```

```js
console.log(moment(`${'2018-04-02'}T${'16:30'}`).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a"))

/* if date is already moment object */
const time = "16:30".split(':');
const momentObj = moment("2018-04-02"); //creating a moment obj for demo
momentObj.set({hours: time[0], minutes: time[1]});
console.log(momentObj.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising! I should have mentioned that my date is already a moment object due to material-moment-date-module. So, with the code you posted above, I have an `invalid date` error.

Comment: (I posted what the object looks like at the bottom of my original question, for reference.)

Comment: This is great, gets me exactly what I need and I learned a lot about Moment too. Thank you!

Comment: @Kenny happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

i believe there must be a problem in the format you are using. `moment(this.webcastForms.value[0].time, 'HH:MM');`

format for minutes is `mm` but you used `MM` which is for month number.Try changing it to

`moment(this.webcastForms.value[0].time, 'HH:mm').format('hh:mm A');`

Comment: Wow, great catch! I was assuming the capitals were for military time, Thanks for this!

Comment: 'hh:mm A' format won't bind to time input field but 'HH:mm' format creates a 24 hour clock time that automatically displays as AM or PM.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer